# Adding a global store for a transformer to consume

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to add a global store for a Transformer to use? In the docs for transformer it says:

"Transform each record of the input stream into zero or more records in the output stream (both key and value type can be altered arbitrarily). A Transformer (provided by the given TransformerSupplier) is applied to each input record and computes zero or more output records. In order to assign a state, the state must be created and registered beforehand via stores added via **addStateStore** or **addGlobalStore** before they can be connected to the Transformer"

yet, the API for **addGlobalStore** on takes a ProcessSupplier?

```
addGlobalStore(storeBuilder: StoreBuilder[_ <: StateStore],
                     topic: String,
                     consumed: Consumed[_, _],
                     stateUpdateSupplier: ProcessorSupplier[_, _])
```

My end goal is to the Kafka Streams DSL, with a transformer since I need a flatMap and transform both keys and values to my output topic. I do not have a processor in my topology tho.

I would expect something like this:

```
addGlobalStore(storeBuilder: StoreBuilder[_ <: StateStore], topic: String, consumed: Consumed[_, ], stateUpdateSupplier: TransformerSupplier[, _])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Processor` that is passed into `addGlobalStore()` is use to maintain (ie, write) the store. Note, that's it's expected atm that this `Processor` copies the data as-is into the store (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7663).

After you have added a global store, you can also add a `Transformer` and the `Transformer` can access the store. Note, that it's not required to connect a global store to make it available (only "regular" stores, would need to be added). Also note, that a `Transformer` only gets read access to global stores.

Comment: Any progress on this ticket? Have found this on kafka-streams 2.0.1.

Comment: Seems nobody picked it up. Feel free to pick it up :) -- Apache Kafka is a community project after all :)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax When would one use GlobalStateStore v/s a GlobalKTable? I want to load a kafka topic's data into memory so I can look up some static id mappings in my kafka stream's application.

Comment: Both are basically the same. Seem GlobalKTable is preferable as it's simpler to use.

Comment: How to access globalStateStore from inside a transformer, any example? When tried accessing the same, it throws exception with could not lock the global state store, probably multiple streams running on same host.

Comment: If you run multiple `KafkaStreams` clients on the same host, you need to isolate them by configuring a different `state.dir` for each client.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Processor instead of Transformer, for all the transformations you want to perform on the input topic, whenever there is a usecase of lookingup data from GlobalStateStore . Use `context.forward(key,value,childName)` to send the data to the downstream nodes. `context.forward(key,value,childName)` may be called multiple times in a `process()` and `punctuate()` , so as to send multiple records to downstream node. If there is a requirement to update GlobalStateStore, do this only in **Processor** passed to `addGlobalStore(..)` because, there is a GlobalStreamThread associated with GlobalStateStore, which keeps the state of the store consistent across all the running kstream instances.